# Cordova/PhoneGap Build Error

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build, mobile-application

I am getting the following error when I am trying to build my phonegap project.

```
D:\LWMobile\hello>cordova build android
.
.
.

BUILD FAILED
C:\AndroidSDK\adtbundle\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:601: The following
d while executing this line:
C:\AndroidSDK\adtbundle\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:720: The following
d while executing this line:
C:\AndroidSDK\adtbundle\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:734: Class not foun

Total time: 2 seconds
Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,ant,debug,-f,D:\LWMo
atforms\android\build.xml,-Dout.dir=ant-build,-Dgen.absolute.dir=an
Error: D:\LWMobile\hello\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat: Comma
h exit code 2
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\aniruddha.b\AppData\Roaming\
les\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:135:
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:823:5)
```

**I am on 64-bit machine and have installed JDK 8 64-bit.
The following are my system path variables:**

```
ANT_HOME: C:\Users\aniruddha.b\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ant\ant
JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20
CLASSPATH: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\lib

PATH: %JAVA_HOME%\bin;
C:\AndroidSDK\adtbundle\sdk\platform-tools;
C:\AndroidSDK\adtbundle\sdk\tools;
C:\Program Files\nodejs\;
%ANT_HOME%\bin;
```

My Project path is: D:\LWMobile\hello

"hello" is the project folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the incompatibility of the Ant version with your Java version.

Ant version you have is 1.8.4. JDK 8 - supports only Ant 1.9 & greater

Uninstall JDK8 and revert back to JDK7

Answer (score 1):

The issue was with the incompatibility of the Ant version with my Java version.

Ant version I have is 1.8.4.
Initially, I had JDK 8 - which supports only Ant 1.9 & greater

Therefore, I uninstalled JDK8 and reverted back to JDK7

Yes, I could have rather updated Ant itself. That is also an option. However, I particularly needed Ant1.8